# jump to some line of EditText or TextView with multiline

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, multiline

I have a multi-line EditText/TextView, say 1000 line.

The contents can't be shown on one page, actually there will automatically be a vertical scroll bar.

I want to make a button that can jump to line 500, and the result view start from exactly at line 500.

Anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the scroll in the Y direction using `TextView.getLineHeight(), TextView.getLineCount() and TextView.getHeight()`.
From there you can call `TextView.scrollTo(0, calculatedY)`.
I'm assuming you always want to have the left side of the view visible.  Of course, if your lines were longer than the current View could display, you could similarly calculate an X scroll position also.

Comment: Hi Larry, Thanks for the hint. Actually, I have a EditText within a ScrollView, I can get total hight by mEditText.getHeight(), but mEditText.scrollTo() result in strange, nevertheless mScrollView.scrollto() works fine! thank you^^.